# A row that is a symbolic link to another by primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We are processing very large amount of data automatically and when humans found out rows like these:

```
4, The Capitol Hill
16, Capitol Hill
22, Hill, Capitol
```

Whose PKs (4, 16, 22, etc.) are all linked to different rows of other data entities across the databases.

It's very time consuming and painful to normalize these links to a single PK since there are so many links; and probably pointless to do so because these could very well happen again and again in future.

Is there any way, preferably native ones, in MySQL that supports some sort of symbolic link between rows? So we can easily modify the row 16 and row 22 to be mere symbolic links of the row 4?

So when 16 or 22 is selected or updated, row 4 would take the effect.

We can do this in application level by adding an extra column `link_id` like this:

```
4, The Capitol Hill, 0
16, , 4
22, , 4
```

But it unnecessarily complicates all queries. A select of the row must first be performed to see if it's a symbolic link or not. If it's not, do everything as usual. If it is, get its link_id and do the link_id row instead.

Is there any better or native way?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

**Fix the data.**

(Actually, that is too short for a comment. ;)  But, mangling your data structure to get around data problems is not the right approach.

One approach is to maintain the address as the primary key throughout the system.  Then you know it is an address.

Another approach is to turn the address into an "address nickname" and to use this everywhere.  Getting the canonical address requires joining back to the master address table.  I don't like this approach, because it can lead to hierarchical structures.

Yes, you will have to update a bunch of tables to get the foreign key relationships correct or update a bunch of queries.  However, the benefits of having the data stored correctly almost always outweigh this complication.  Somewhere down the line, someone will not understand that two references in a table are really to the same address.  S/he will make a mistake, and that mistake could be much more expensive than fixing the data in the first place.

Comment: What if we can't fix it? The redundant IDs are referenced by so many client data that we have no control over. We are in the data API business and once the PK / ID of a particular row is published, it's a done deal. What is the best option in this situation?